# Visual Studio 2008: Creating Single DLL from Solution with Many Projects

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, deployment, dll, assemblies

I have an ASP.NET web application developed in Visual Studio 2008, composed of 3 different projects (one for UI, one of [BO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_object_%28computer_science%29) and the third for [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_abstraction_layer)).

How can I generate a single assembly file which holds all 3? Now it's generating 3 DLLS each for each project in the solution.

Comment: Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of have an n-tier project?

Comment: Might be for ease of deployment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not know if there's indeed this feature in VS2008. But you certainly can do it outside VS.

E.g.:
[Merging .NET assemblies using ILMerge](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mergingassemblies.aspx)

Answer (score 17):

For each of your projects create a netmodule or an assembly and compile/merge them all into a single assembly.

**First alternative.** This was proposed by [Jay R. Wren](http://jrwren.wrenfam.com/blog/):

> This is a cute hack, but with the CSC and VBC both supporting the **`/target:module`** and **`/addmodule`** options, you could actually do this without ILMerge just by using a shell script or make file.
>
> Visual Studio doesn't support the "netmodule" type, but MSBuild does.
>
> Add the VB project to your solution. Unload the project and edit the project file.
>
> Change OutputType to module:

```
<OutputType>module</OutputType>
```

> Instead of adding a reference to the desired project, we add a module. Sadly, again VStudio fails here, but MSBUILD works just fine. Unload the project and edit the project file. Add an item group with AddModules include directives.

```
<ItemGroup><AddModules Include="..\VbXml\bin\Debug\VbXml.netmodule" /></ItemGroup>
```

> This will tell msbuild to tell CSC to use **`/addmodule`** directives, just like the Reference Item Group which Studio does manage.
>
> <strike>Major Drawback: No Visual Studio Intellisense for the added module. We already have references, it is too bad we don't have modules.</strike> [UPDATE: As [@Ark-kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497385/ark-kun) pointed out elsewhere, Visual Studio can reference **`.netmodule`** projects and have Intellisense. Just add the project reference BEFORE changing the output type.]
>
> SharpDevelop has the first step, but the second step, an "Add Module" gui has been open as a low priority item since SD 2.0.

**Second way.** This [great article](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/MixingLanguagesInASingleAssemblyInVisualStudioSeamlesslyWithILMergeAndMSBuild.aspx) (by Scott Hanselman) describes how to megre assemblies automatically if you're using Visual Studio.  It **does** give you IntelliSense support <strike>, unlike the first alternative</strike>.

**Third way.** Do it manually with scs.
Example how to create several modules and link theme into a single dll:

```
csc /t:module RarelyUsedTypes.cs
csc /out:AllTypes.dll /t:library /addmodule:RarelyUsedTypes.netmodule AllTypes.cs
```

For more information see Richter's book [CLR via C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627045).

Comment: All three ways produce a single assembly. But only the second way gives you a single **file**.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ASP.NET Merge Tool (Aspnet_merge.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397866.aspx)