# .NET and DLL's in several projects

Tags: .net, dll

My current issue is I have a DLL which has a class I use as an abstraction for my Database Mappers. I use this DLL in all my projects (including other class libraries/dlls) that access the database. My issue is that every time I update my Data Mapper dll I have to updating it in all the other dll's I am using in my main project as well (right now this means 3 other class libraries). When I am trying to debug the dll library on my main project this becomes a lot of work for each small change. Is there a better way to approach this?

Thanks.

Comment: Are your updates changing the interface that the other libraries use?  If so, then you might need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood the question properly, here are two possibilities:

- Reference the project source rather than the assembly in your various projects.
- Create a post build task that copies your shared assembly dll to a central location that your other projects can access it from. Something like:

  copy "$(TargetPath)" $(SolutionDir)SharedAssemblies\$(TargetFileName)

Answer (score 0):

From the wording of your question it seems that you're linking into a mapper like LINQ and using the classes that it generates are your model classes, thus resulting in changes all over when you recompile.

**If this is the case:**
You might want to consider creating your own models and mapping them to the data mapper classes generated.  Look at something like the [Repository Pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html).  Then you basically create a layer above your data mapper, and your application uses that layer.

**If this is not the case:**

- Don't reference the dll, reference
  the project.
- Compile all your
  assemblies into one, or you can use
  something like [ILMerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ILMerge.aspx) to make
  one assembly as well.

Comment: For compiling assemblies into one, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878807/visual-studio-2008-creating-single-dll-from-solution-with-many-projects